# Asp mvc map url with hardcoded controller and action can't be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have next map url definition where I want to set specific action and controller for special url:
//localhost:55321/SpecificPart/UserTextId all other routes should work in default way

but based on Route Debugger my URL is mapping to my main route rule how to handle this case ?

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "PartnerSighUp",
                "SpecificPart/{id}",
                  new { controller = "SpecificController ", action = "SpecificAction" },
                  new { id = "[A-Za-z].+" }
           );

   routes.MapRoute(
                name: "EnglishHomePage",
                url: "",
                defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", culture = "en", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

**Update** if SpecificPart = SpecificController (controller name) it is working but if SpecificPart  != SpecificController and looks to other controller it is not working

Comment: What's the value for "UserTextId", because it's apparently not matching the regex? Also, please only tag your question with specific version numbers if the question is related to that specific version. You're not running *both* MVC4 and MVC5, and even then, this is just basic routing that is virtually unchanged since MVC1. In other words, it's not version-dependent.

Comment: for example a2 but UserTextId should be this value as well

Comment: @Andrei: the regex says only the first letter must be alpha, followed by one or more of any kind of character (notice the `.`)

Comment: I have ranamed {id} to other name and it started work